# prevent wrapping in IE7/8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, word-wrap

I have come a crossed the `IE > TD > white-space:nowrap;` bug and have attempted to implement the fix described in multiple places (here included) which was to move the `white-space:nowrap;` to a `<span>` element and wrap the contents of the TD in a span.

This however is also not working (at least IE7/8 maybe IE9 and don't care about IE6). [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/F826J/1/) is an example of my code. 
*Be advised I have included my specific jQuery to initiate the buttons in the affected cell, and all of my CSS*

The table cell widths are set to circumvent the columns from growing with the page, if this is the issue then my solution is to hard code the last column width. I am OK with that (however I would like to know why the white-space is being ignored)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `white-space: nowrap` is being ignored because you are using `:last-child` in the CSS selector:

```
.data-table th, .data-table td:last-child span {
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: center;
}
```

IE8 and below do not support this selector.

#### Edit

To prevent wrapping in IE7/8 you could assign a class to the last table cell or change the CSS to focus on all spans in the table:

**All span tags:**

```
.data-table th, .data-table td span {
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: center;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/F826J/2/

**Using class:**

```
.data-table th, .data-table td.last span {
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: center;
}

<table>
    <tr>...</tr>
    ....
    <tr class="last">...</tr>
</table>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/F826J/3/

Comment: ugh.. I completely forgot IE hates most if not all of the new CSS3 selectors. that is what I get for not having IE installed and testing for it only when i'm near completion.

Comment: Yeah, I thought you'd prob kick yourself after I pointed it out